# Type mismatch: inferred type is String but KaptOptions was expected

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, build.gradle, kapt

## When I use the latest version of Android Studio, I am facing with this problem. On my other project exactly same dependencies are implemented, but there is no problem. Here I am facing these kinds of errors

`Type mismatch: inferred type is String but KaptOptions was expected Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> Unit but KaptOptions was expected Unresolved reference: correctErrorTypes`

**Here is my build.gradle(Module) file:**

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt

plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id ("kotlin-kapt")
    id ("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.urahimli.booklistbeta"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.urahimli.booklistbeta"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.3.2"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")


    // Compose dependencies
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.1")
    implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.0")
    implementation ("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0-alpha01")

    // Coroutines
    implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.2")
    implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.2")

    //Dagger - Hilt
    implementation ("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.46.1")
    kapt ("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.46.1")
    kapt ("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0")

    // Room
    implementation ("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.2")
    kapt ("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2")

    // Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation ("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.2")

    //material 3
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.5.0")
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
```

**and here is my build.gradle(Project) file:**

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.10" apply false

    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.8.10-1.0.9" apply false
}
```

as I said, I think all these things happen after creating a new project. On my old project, there is no problem. I need your solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing

```kotlin
id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.47" apply false
```

In your project-level `build.gradle.kts` file.

I tested adding it in and that seems to fix it.

Comment: thanks for your help, it helps me and now my project is running

Comment: It does not work for me

Comment: Note that you also need id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") [without the version or apply] in the module using Hilt.